# If $X$ has a open-closed base $\mathcal{B}$ and if $|X|>1$ then $X$ is not locally connected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

> **Statement**
>
> Let be $X$ a topological space that has a open-closed base $\mathcal{B}$. So if $X$ is such that $|X|>1$ then it is not locally connected.
>
> *Proof*. If $X$ was locally connected then for any $x\in X$ there exist a connected neighborhood $V$ of $x$ and so there must exist $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq V$ and so, since $B$ is open and closed, $B$ and $V\setminus B$ is two open disjoint set of $V$ such that $B\cup V\setminus B=V$, that means that $V$ is not connected.

Clearly the proof is correct iff $B\subset V$: indeed only in this case it follow that $V\setminus B\neq\varnothing$. Anyway I see that any discrete space $X$ is a space such that have a open-closed base and it is locally connected: so it seems that the statement is false; however my text says the contrary so I ask if we add other hypothesis then the statement is true. So how to prove the statement? Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x\in X$ let $\mathscr{B}(x)=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:x\in B\}$; it’s enough to add the requirement that there be a point $x_0\in X$ such that $\bigcap\mathscr{B}(x_0)$ is not open. (This is automatic if, for instance, $X$ is $T_1$ but not discrete.)

Let $H=\bigcap\mathscr{B}(x_0)$, and let $V$ be an open nbhd of $x_0$; then $H\subsetneqq V$, so fix $x\in V\setminus H$. There are $B_0,B_1\in\mathscr{B}(x_0)$ such that $B_0\subseteq V$ and $x\notin B_1$. Let $U=B_0\cap B_1$; then $U$ is clopen, and $x_0\in U\subseteq V\setminus\{x\}$, so $U$ and $V\setminus U$ are disjoint, non-empty open subsets of $V$ whose union is $V$.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand why there exist $B_0,B_1\in\mathscr{B}(x)$ such that $B_0\subseteq V$ and $x\notin B_1$; then I don't understand why $U$ is clopen. Finally if $U$ and $V\setminus U$ is a separation of $V$ the it seems that $V$ is not connected and so why can we conclude that $X$ is not locally connected? Could you explain, please? I'm sorry, forgive my confusion.

Comment: Perhaps I understand the first point. If $X$ is $T_1$ there exist an open nhood $A$ of $x_0$ such that $x_0\in A$ and $x\notin A$ and so there exist $B_0\in\mathscr{B}(x)$ such that $B_0\subseteq A\cap V\subseteq V$. Anyway how to prove that tere exist $B_1\in\mathscr{B}(x)$ such that $x\notin B_1$? Certainly I could choose $B_1=B_0$ but it would be strange.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: I am not assuming that $X$ is $T_1$. $\mathscr{B}(x_0)$ is a local base at $x_0$, and $V$ is an open nbhd of $x_0$, so there must be some $B_0\in\mathscr{B}(x_0)$ such that $x_0\in B\subseteq V$. If $x\notin\bigcap\mathscr{B}(x_0)$, so there must be some $B_1\in\mathscr{B}(x_0)$ such that $x\notin B_1$. $B_0$ and $B_1$ are clopen, so their intersection is clopen. Finally, $V$ is an **arbitrary** open nbhd of $x$, and we’ve shown that it’s not connected, so $x$ has **no** connected open nbhd.

Comment: Okay. Finally could I ask to you why are $B_0$ and $B_1$ clopen?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Because they’re members of the clopen base $\mathscr{B}$: remember that $\mathscr{B}(x_0)$ is just the collection of members of $\mathscr{B}$ that contain $x_0$, so they’re all open.

Comment: Okay, now it is all clear. Thanks too much!!!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You’re welcome! That one was fun.

Comment: However you proved that $x_0$ has not open connected nbhd: so how can I conclude that $X$ is not locally connected? Indeed my text says that $X$ is locally connected iff for each $x\in X$ there exist a connected local base. Could you explain this to me, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: Anyway if don't exist open connected nbhd of $x_0$ then there not exist an open connected local basis of $x_0$; but unfortunately not all local bases are open.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: A space is locally connected iff each pooint has a local nbhd base of connected **open** sets; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space#Definitions_and_first_examples), for instance. Possibly your book uses the same terminology that I learned many years ago: a base or local base consists of open sets, and if one wants to allow non-open neighborhoods, one speaks of a (local) **neighborhood** base.

Comment: I reread what my text says: "X is locally connected if for any $x\in X$ there exist a local base of connected nbhd". You can read for yourself [here](http://lya.fciencias.unam.mx/tamariz/notas/LibroCasarrubiasTamariz.pdf) -definition 8.19 at page 266.

Comment: Anyway I know that $X$ is locally connected iff each component of each open set is open: so, using the definition of my text, can I conclude from this that $X$ is locally connected iff $X$ has a open local base connected?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: I’d forgotten that although weak local connectedness (your property) and local connectedness (my property) are not equivalent at a point, they **are** equivalent globally. You know from Prop. 8.23 that a space is weakly locally connected iff components of open sets are open. Now just prove that a space is locally connected iff components of open sets are open; it’s a slightly simpler version of the same argument. It follows that the two notions of local connectedness are equivalent, and you’re done.

Comment: Okay, so if $X$ is locally connected then for each $x\in X$ there exist an open local base $\mathcal{B}(x)$ of connected nbhd and so trivially $X$ is weakly locally connected. Vice versa if $X$ is weakly locally connected then the components of open sets are open and so how can now conclude that for each $x\in X$ there exist an open local base $\mathcal{B}(x)$ of connected nbhd? Could you explain this, please? Forgive my insistence.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You’re working too hard. $X$ is weakly locally connected iff components of open sets are open iff $X$ is locally connected. Prop. 8.23 gives you the first equivalence, and the proof of the second is essentially the same.

Comment: So if $X$ is weakly locally connected iff for each $x\in X$ there exist an open local base $\mathcal{B}(x)$ of connected nbhd, then why $X$ is weakly locally connected iff components of open sets are open?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: That’s Proposition 8.23 in your text.

Comment: Okay, so I said bad what I don't understand: excuse me. Now I'll try to explain better. So my text claim that $X$ is locally connected iff for any $x∈X$ there exist a local base of connected nbhd and then through $8.23$ it proves that this is equivalent to claim that components of open sets are open. Now using $8.23$ how to prove that $X$ is locally connected iff for each $x∈X$ there exist an open local base $\mathcal{B}(x)$ of connected nbhd?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Imitate the proof of $8.23$. If $X$ is loc. conn., $U$ is open in $X$, and $C$ is a component of $U$, let $x\in C$; then $x$ has a conn. open nbhd $B_x$ such that $x\in B_x\subseteq U$, and since $B_x$ is conn., we must have $B_x\subseteq C$. Thus, $C=\bigcup_{x\in C}B_x$ is open. Conversely, suppose that components of open sets are open, let $U$ be open, and let $x\in U$; the component of $U$ containing $x$ is a conn. open nbhd of $x$ contained in $U$, so the conn. open nbhds of $x$ are a local base at $x$, and $X$ is loc. conn.

Comment: Okay, now it is clear. However in the second part we have to suppose -it is trivially but it seems to me necessary- that the conmponent of $U$ is not empty, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: That’s not a problem: by definition components are non-empty.

Comment: Why? Indeed in the second part you suppose only that the components of open sets are open: so how can I sure that the components of any open set are not empty?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Because that’s part of the definition of *component*. A component of a set $A$ is a maximal connected subset of $A$. Singletons are always connected, so the empty set is never a maximal connected subset of any non-empty set and hence never a component. (And we don’t generally talk about components of $\varnothing$.)

Comment: My edit was for a typo; the subscript 0 on the x in the 2nd line was missing. BTW  it is sufficient that $X$ is $T_0$ and not discrete.